# Spectral decomposition, Sturm-Liouville

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider $A:L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$ defined as $$ (Af)(s) = \int_0^1 \max\{s,t\}\cdot f(t)\mathrm dt$$
I've shown that the operator is compact and self-adjoint.

Looking for the eigenvalues.

$$(Af)(s) = cf(s) = \int_0^1 \max\{s,t\}\cdot f(t)\mathrm dt$$
then $$c\cdot \frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm ds} = \int_0^s f(t)\mathrm dt$$
and $$c\cdot \frac{\mathrm d^2f}{\mathrm ds^2} = f(s).$$

Obviously $$\frac{\mathrm df(0)}{\mathrm ds} = 0.$$

How can I get another initial condition?

Comment: Please rember that Latex cannot be considered an optional on this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other condition occurs at the other endpoint: 
$$
c f(1) = \int_0^1 f(t)\,dt = cf'(1)
$$
hence $f(1)=f'(1)$.

The general method for finding boundary conditions in such problems is to write down $f(0),f'(0),f(1),f'(1)$ and to stare at them.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @George On the technical side, you may be interested in this: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287)